# AWS Notebook Instance is working but Lambda is not accepting the input

Tags: tensorflow, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I developed an ANN tool by using pycharm/tensorflow on my own computer. I uploaded the h5 and json files to Amazon Sagemaker by creating a Notebook Instance. I was finally able to successfully create an endpoint and make it work. The following code in Notebook Instance -Jupyter works:

```
import json
import boto3
import numpy as np
import io
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
data = np.random.randn(1,6).tolist()
endpoint_name = 'sagemaker-tensorflow-**********'
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, Body=json.dumps(data))
response_body = response['Body']
print(response_body.read())
```

However, the problem occurs when I created a lambda function and call the endpoint from there. The input should be a row of 6 features -that is a 1-by-6 vector. I enter the following input into lambda {"data":"1,1,1,1,1,1"} and it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 20, in lambda_handler
    Body=payload)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

I think the problem is that the input needs to be 1-by-6 instead of 6-by-1 and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the content type you specified is `text/csv`, so try out:

```
{"data": ["1,1,1,1,1,1"]}
```